# change 201401(numeric) in to date variable in R

Tags: r, date

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbjWm.png)

var1 is a numeric variable 
i try as.Date many times 
but it did not work 
I want to change the 201401(year-month) to date variable.

Comment: Assuming your data.frame is named `df`, then do `as.Date(paste0(df$Var1, "01"), format="%Y%m%d")`

Answer (score 0):

Dates also need a day, and you do not have that. So you need to assume which day of the month your are looking at:

```
dat <- data.frame(var1 = c(201401, 201402, 201403), Freq=sample(1:3))

assumed_day <- 15

dat$date <- as.Date(paste(dat$var1, assumed_day), format = "%Y%m %d")

print(dat)        
#    var1 Freq       date
#1 201401    1 2014-01-15
#2 201402    2 2014-02-15
#3 201403    3 2014-03-15
```

See `as.Date`.

Using the format and other related function you can format the dates however you like:

```
dat$formatted <- paste(months(dat$date), format(dat$date, "%Y"))

print(dat)
#    var1 Freq       date     formatted
#1 201401    1 2014-01-15  January 2014
#2 201402    3 2014-02-15 February 2014
#3 201403    2 2014-03-15    March 2014
```

Comment: @孔紫涵 You're welcome. *If* it answers your question, consider selecting it as such (the tick-mark below the up and down-vote arrows).